# TinyMCE editor in dijit.dialog: link dialog not working

Tags: javascript, dojo, tinymce-4

I'm working on my own `CMS`. I use `Dojo Toolkit` (Version: 1.9) and `TinyMCE 4` for this project. The `TinyMCE` editors are shown in `dijit.Dialogs` which are created directly in the `HTML` code (not programmatically). 
I have read about problems with `JQuery` to show toolbars or to fetch the editor content in relation to `JQuery UI` dialogs. But fortunately, these problems don`t occur in my project.
I use the following code to initialize the`TinyMCE` editor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // other dojo.require calls
    dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
    require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/ready", "dojo/json"], function(Button, ready){
        ready(function(){
            loadPageContent();
        });
      });
       // some JQuery initialize for another plugin not related in any way to TinyMCE (displays toast messages)
        $(function() {
            $("#content .grid_5, #content .grid_6").sortable({
                placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
                forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                connectWith: '#content .grid_6, #content .grid_5',
                handle: 'h2',
                revert: true
            });
            $("#content .grid_5, #content .grid_6").disableSelection();
        });
        // The TinyMCE initialization:
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            theme: "modern",
            entity_encoding : "raw",
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                "emoticons template paste textcolor"
            ],
            toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
            toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
            image_advtab: true,
        });
    </script>
```

But if I want to add an link, the link dialog doesn't allow me to insert the URL and the name. My problem is:
The target window can be selected in this `TinyMCE` dialog. If I insert an URL directly in the editor, it is recognized as a link but editing in the link dialog is also impossible.

The HTML code for the `TinyMCE` editor inside the `dijit.Dialog`:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" title="Inhaltselement" id="dialogContentRightElement">
    <div style="width: 45em;">
        <form id="dialogContentElement_form">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Farbe/Stil/Spezialkasten:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="dialogContentRightElement_form_color" id="dialogContentRightElement_form_color">
                        // some options are here
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Titel:</td>
                <td><input dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" required="true" name="dialogContentRightElement_form_title" id="dialogContentRightElement_form_title"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Inhalt:</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <textarea style="width: 42em; height: 20em;" id="dialogContentRightElement_form_content" name="dialogContentRightElement_form_content"></textarea>
        <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onClick="saveContentRightNew()">Speichern</button><button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onClick="dijit.byId('dialogContentRightElement').hide()">Abbrechen</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Found a bug report related to this issue: http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5934

Answer (score 1):

Solution found: use `dojox.layout.FloatingPane` instead of `dijit.Dialog`. But I would not recommend the usage of `dojox.layout.FloatingPane`, I had lots of problems so I switched back and will wait until TinyMCE update will fix the problem.